# How does a DLL dependency link to a different project, and when should I rebuild a project with a DLL dependency

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

I have 1 Visual Studio 2015 solution with 2 projects:

- **Foo** (windows console application)
- **Bar** (ASP.NET web application (MVC))

**Bar** has:

```
public void DoBaz()
public void SomethingUnrelatedPublic()
private void SomethingUnrelatedPrivate()
```

**Foo** has a reference to the **Bar** project DLL, and has:

```
Bar.DoBaz()
```

I do not quite understand how the dependency from project **Foo** to project **Bar** works. I want to know if I would need to rebuild and redeploy project **Foo** after changing the following to project **Bar**:

- Changing the name/method signature of `DoBaz()`, which is directly called by project **Foo** *(I assume it would crash if I don't)*
- Changing the content of `DoBaz()`, which is directly called by project **Foo** *(I'm not sure)*
- Changing the name/method signature of `SomethingUnrelatedPublic()`, which is not called, might be referenced *(Not sure)*
- Changing the content  of `SomethingUnrelatedPublic()`, which is not called, and I guess not referenced *(Not sure)*
- Changing the name/method/content signature of `SomethingUnrelatedPrivate()` *(I guess not)*
- Changing something in the project settings or web.xml *(I guess so)*

Of course I also want to know why: does project **Foo** link only to public interfaces base on function name and method signature? Or does it link to other things?

Comment: Any changes in the public interface of Bar inevitably requires you to make corresponding changes in Foo.  So VS automatically builds both and you have to redeploy both.  Anything internal doesn't, but VS will rebuild Foo anyway since the Bar assembly was changed.  You'd have to wrangle a plugin style app with interfaces to avoid that.  Technically you could know that you don't have to redeploy Foo, but it is risky of course.  It usually takes getting this wrong two or three times until you say "ah, the heck with it".

Comment: Very insightful